# Laravel Controller - template. suppress the master template

Tags: php, ajax, templates, laravel

I am getting started with Laravel. I have a controller which shows and inserts the data. It is similar to

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

     protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

     public function showProfile()
     {
         $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
     }

     public function addProfile()
     {
         <Insertion Logic>
         echo "Successfully added";
     }

}
```

Now insert is a ajax call. So I want to display the just the Success message after adding to the database. But in my case the layout content also shows up. How can I just return the echo message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you inside a method, you will be able to access and change a protected property.

You can just simply add `$this->layout = '';` right before you do the echo.